# no images compressed using imagemin in nodejs

Tags: node.js, multer, imagemin

I am using multer to upload images to the server and imagemin to compress the images. But when i am unable to do compress the image.

```
   app.post('/upload',(req,res)=>{
   upload(req,res,(err)=>{
    if(err){
        res.render('picupload',{
            msg: err
        });
    }else{
       if(req.file == undefined){
           res.render('picupload',{
               msg: 'Error: No File selected!'
           });
       } else{
        console.log(req.file);
        imagemin([ `uploads/${req.file.filename}`], 'uploads/compressed', {
            plugins: [
                imageminJpegtran(),
                imageminPngquant({quality: '65-80'})
            ]
        }).then(files => {
            console.log(files);

        });
        res.render(pathjoin13,{
            file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}` ,
            file_comp: `uploads/compressed/${req.file.filename}`
          });
         }
        }
       });
     });
```

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: none.. its just return an empty array on console in imagemin

Comment: i think in imagemin([ `uploads/${req.file.filename}`) you also have to specify file extension

Comment: no.. filename has an extension attached to it. .nyway i fugured out the problem.  The destination folder path was not correct